# PCM3168 ADC "DOUT" Output

Tags: audio

The datasheet for the PCM3168 6ch ADC states that ADC 1-2 is outputted digitally out of DOUT1 and 3-4 DOUT2 etc. How are both of these sent down the single digital pin and how can I handle this digital audio, say send it to a computer via USB microcontroller or other format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sent with I2S protocol. There are pictures in the datasheet. Your microcontroller then needs to have I2S port to receive this and it has to look like USB sound device to the PC.